# What is the Cheapest way to track my balloon (only altitude or gps coordinates)?

Tags: gps, tracking, altitude

I want to build extreme cheap high altitude stuff - balloon, paper plane :) anything. Its cold outside now, and i dont want to track, and collect the my landed "spacecraft".
So, i need a very cheap solution to track, at least the altitude of it.

What solution you advice? Thanks.

Comment: A balloon would not reach space. This is no question for Space Exploration StackExchange.

Comment: Balloon can be a part of a cheap spacecraft. the first step is to go near space. dont be pessimistic, the future is ours!

Comment: Hi Norbert have a look around at the site and see what kinds of questions are well received here and result in answers. They tend to be fairly well focused on a specific issued and usually show some research that the author has done first.